# Extract nested <a> elements from a JSON string

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, recursion

I am trying to find all "a" keys in a JSON string and save them in an array. Since they may be nested at different levels, I'm using recursion to traverse each key's children to exhaustively list all "a" keys. However, I cannot wrap my head around recursing the child nodes and appending any found "a" keys to the returned array. Any help here would be appreciated.

The function for traversing the JSON string:

```
searchForKeys = (keyValue, obj) => {

  let arrayOfKeys = [];

  if (obj instanceof Array) {
    obj.forEach((item, index) => {

     if(typeof(item) === 'object' && Object.keys(item)[index] === keyValue) {
        console.log('pushing found item to return array');
        arrayOfKeys.push(...item);
        console.log(arrayOfKeys);
     } 
    });
  }
  else if (typeof(obj) === 'object') {
    if (Object.keys(obj).length > 0) {
      let itemName;
      for(let i = 0; i < Object.keys(obj).length; i++) {
        itemName = Object.keys(obj)[i];
        if (itemName === keyValue) {
          console.log('pushing found item to return array');
          arrayOfKeys.push(obj[itemName]);
        }
      }
      console.log('arrayOfKeys.length:', arrayOfKeys.length);
      arrayOfKeys.push(searchForKeys(keyValue, obj[itemName]));
  }
  return arrayOfKeys;
  }
};

let returnedArray = searchForKeys("a", dummyJSON);

console.log("array content:\n", [...returnedArray]); 
console.log("array length", returnedArray.length);
```

The expected result is returnedArray to contain all four "a" keys from the JSON object.

The source data:

```
const dummyJSON = {
  "a": {
    "@attributes": {
      "href": "/URL/2021.html?q=link+value",
      "title": "Lautsprecher",
      "class": "catfilter-list-link",
      "data-gtm-event": "filter.click",
      "data-gtm-payload": "{\"event_category\":\"mainsearch\",\"event_action\":\"quickfilter.click\",\"event_label\":\"quickfilter\",\"position\":\"1\",\"location\":\"headline\"}",
      "data-metric-click": "mainsearch-catfilter-click"
    },
    "#text": "Lautsprecher"
  },
  "ul": {
    "@attributes": {
      "class": "catfilter-list"
    },
    "#text": [],
    "li": [
      {
        "@attributes": {
          "class": "catfilter-list-item"
        },
        "#text": [
          "",
          ""
        ],
        "a": {
          "@attributes": {
            "href": "/URL/8412.html?q=link+value",
            "title": "Handy-Ladegeräte",
            "class": "catfilter-list-link",
            "data-gtm-event": "filter.click",
            "data-gtm-payload": "{\"event_category\":\"mainsearch\",\"event_action\":\"quickfilter.click\",\"event_label\":\"quickfilter\",\"position\":\"1\",\"location\":\"headline\"}",
            "data-metric-click": "mainsearch-catfilter-click"
          },
          "#text": "Handy-Ladegeräte"
        }
      },
      {
        "@attributes": {
          "class": "catfilter-list-item"
        },
        "#text": [
          "",
          ""
        ],
        "a": {
          "@attributes": {
            "href": "/URL/26136.html?q=link+value",
            "title": "Kabellose Ladegeräte",
            "class": "catfilter-list-link",
            "data-gtm-event": "filter.click",
            "data-gtm-payload": "{\"event_category\":\"mainsearch\",\"event_action\":\"quickfilter.click\",\"event_label\":\"quickfilter\",\"position\":\"1\",\"location\":\"headline\"}",
            "data-metric-click": "mainsearch-catfilter-click"
          },
          "#text": "Kabellose Ladegeräte"
        }
      },
      {
        "@attributes": {
          "class": "catfilter-list-item"
        },
        "a": {
          "@attributes": {
            "href": "/URL/2021.html?q=link+value",
            "title": "Lautsprecher",
            "class": "catfilter-list-link",
            "data-gtm-event": "filter.click",
            "data-gtm-payload": "{\"event_category\":\"mainsearch\",\"event_action\":\"quickfilter.click\",\"event_label\":\"quickfilter\",\"position\":\"1\",\"location\":\"headline\"}",
            "data-metric-click": "mainsearch-catfilter-click"
          },
          "#text": "Lautsprecher"
        },
        "#text": [
          "",
          ""
        ],
        "a": {
          "@attributes": {
            "href": "/URL/2021.html?q=link+value",
            "title": "Lautsprecher",
            "class": "catfilter-list-link",
            "data-gtm-event": "filter.click",
            "data-gtm-payload": "{\"event_category\":\"mainsearch\",\"event_action\":\"quickfilter.click\",\"event_label\":\"quickfilter\",\"position\":\"1\",\"location\":\"headline\"}",
            "data-metric-click": "mainsearch-catfilter-click"
          },
          "#text": "Lautsprecher"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: What type of app are you creating - node.js or web?

Comment: it's a node.js based one.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: There is no such thing as a _JSON Object_ - JSON is always a string.

Comment: @Quentin, thanks for pointing out. Will take into account in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For JSON string, the [`JSON.parse` reviver parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter) can be used :

```js
var arr = [], json = JSON.stringify({"a":{"@attributes":{"href":"/URL/2021.html?q=link+value","title":"Lautsprecher","class":"catfilter-list-link","data-gtm-event":"filter.click","data-gtm-payload":"{\"event_category\":\"mainsearch\",\"event_action\":\"quickfilter.click\",\"event_label\":\"quickfilter\",\"position\":\"1\",\"location\":\"headline\"}","data-metric-click":"mainsearch-catfilter-click"},"#text":"Lautsprecher"},"ul":{"@attributes":{"class":"catfilter-list"},"#text":[],"li":[{"@attributes":{"class":"catfilter-list-item"},"#text":["",""],"a":{"@attributes":{"href":"/URL/8412.html?q=link+value","title":"Handy-Ladegeräte","class":"catfilter-list-link","data-gtm-event":"filter.click","data-gtm-payload":"{\"event_category\":\"mainsearch\",\"event_action\":\"quickfilter.click\",\"event_label\":\"quickfilter\",\"position\":\"1\",\"location\":\"headline\"}","data-metric-click":"mainsearch-catfilter-click"},"#text":"Handy-Ladegeräte"}},{"@attributes":{"class":"catfilter-list-item"},"#text":["",""],"a":{"@attributes":{"href":"/URL/26136.html?q=link+value","title":"Kabellose Ladegeräte","class":"catfilter-list-link","data-gtm-event":"filter.click","data-gtm-payload":"{\"event_category\":\"mainsearch\",\"event_action\":\"quickfilter.click\",\"event_label\":\"quickfilter\",\"position\":\"1\",\"location\":\"headline\"}","data-metric-click":"mainsearch-catfilter-click"},"#text":"Kabellose Ladegeräte"}},{"@attributes":{"class":"catfilter-list-item"},"a":{"@attributes":{"href":"/URL/2021.html?q=link+value","title":"Lautsprecher","class":"catfilter-list-link","data-gtm-event":"filter.click","data-gtm-payload":"{\"event_category\":\"mainsearch\",\"event_action\":\"quickfilter.click\",\"event_label\":\"quickfilter\",\"position\":\"1\",\"location\":\"headline\"}","data-metric-click":"mainsearch-catfilter-click"},"#text":"Lautsprecher"},"#text":["",""],"a":{"@attributes":{"href":"/URL/2021.html?q=link+value","title":"Lautsprecher","class":"catfilter-list-link","data-gtm-event":"filter.click","data-gtm-payload":"{\"event_category\":\"mainsearch\",\"event_action\":\"quickfilter.click\",\"event_label\":\"quickfilter\",\"position\":\"1\",\"location\":\"headline\"}","data-metric-click":"mainsearch-catfilter-click"},"#text":"Lautsprecher"}}]}})

JSON.parse(json, (key, val) => key == 'a' ? arr.push(val) : val)

console.log( arr )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible way using `Array.prototype.flatMap` -

```
const valuesForProp = (q = "", o = {}) =>
  Object (o) === o
    ? Object
        .entries (o)
        .flatMap
          ( ([ k, v ]) =>
              k === q
                ? [ v, ...valuesForProp (q, v) ]
                : valuesForProp (q, v)
          )
    : []
```

Let's use a simplified `data` and test the output -

```
const data =
  { a: { b: 0, c: { a: 1 } }
  , b: [ { a: 2 } ]
  , c: { d: 0 }
  , e: { f: { g: { h: { a: 3 } } } }
  , i: { j: [ { a: 4 }, { a: 5 } ] }
  }


valuesForProp ("a", data)
// => [ { b: 0, c: { a: 1 } }, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

valuesForProp ("b", data)
// => [ 0, [ { a: 2 } ] ]

valuesForProp ("c", data)
// => [ { a: 1 }, { d: 0 } ]

valuesForProp ("z", data)
// => []
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
const data =
  { a: { b: 0, c: { a: 1 } }
  , b: [ { a: 2 } ]
  , c: { d: 0 }
  , e: { f: { g: { h: { a: 3 } } } }
  , i: { j: [ { a: 4 }, { a: 5 } ] }
  }

const valuesForProp = (q = "", o = {}) =>
  Object (o) === o
    ? Object
        .entries (o)
        .flatMap
          ( ([ k, v ]) =>
              k === q
                ? [ v, ...valuesForProp (q, v) ]
                : valuesForProp (q, v)
          )
    : []

console .log (valuesForProp ("a", data))
// => [ { b: 0, c: { a: 1 } }, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

console .log (valuesForProp ("b", data))
// => [ 0, [ { a: 2 } ] ]

console .log (valuesForProp ("c", data))
// => [ { a: 1 }, { d: 0 } ]

console .log (valuesForProp ("z", data))
// => []
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to query JSON subsections is [JSONPath expressions](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html), to resolve this task just need to apply **$..a**-expression to recursively select all required descendants (see [example](https://repl.it/repls/GlumImaginaryMarkuplanguage)).

```
var JSONPath = require('JSONPath');

JSONPath({
  json: dummyJSON, 
  path: '$..a',
  flatten: true, 
  callback: (result) => {
    console.log(result);
}});
```

The source data:

```
const dummyJSON = {
  "a": {
    "@attributes": {
      "href": "/URL/2021.html?q=link+value",
      "title": "Lautsprecher",
      "class": "catfilter-list-link",
      "data-gtm-event": "filter.click",
      "data-gtm-payload": "{\"event_category\":\"mainsearch\",\"event_action\":\"quickfilter.click\",\"event_label\":\"quickfilter\",\"position\":\"1\",\"location\":\"headline\"}",
      "data-metric-click": "mainsearch-catfilter-click"
    },
    "#text": "Lautsprecher"
  },
  "ul": {
    "@attributes": {
      "class": "catfilter-list"
    },
    "#text": [],
    "li": [
      {
        "@attributes": {
          "class": "catfilter-list-item"
        },
        "#text": [
          "",
          ""
        ],
        "a": {
          "@attributes": {
            "href": "/URL/8412.html?q=link+value",
            "title": "Handy-Ladegeräte",
            "class": "catfilter-list-link",
            "data-gtm-event": "filter.click",
            "data-gtm-payload": "{\"event_category\":\"mainsearch\",\"event_action\":\"quickfilter.click\",\"event_label\":\"quickfilter\",\"position\":\"1\",\"location\":\"headline\"}",
            "data-metric-click": "mainsearch-catfilter-click"
          },
          "#text": "Handy-Ladegeräte"
        }
      },
      {
        "@attributes": {
          "class": "catfilter-list-item"
        },
        "#text": [
          "",
          ""
        ],
        "a": {
          "@attributes": {
            "href": "/URL/26136.html?q=link+value",
            "title": "Kabellose Ladegeräte",
            "class": "catfilter-list-link",
            "data-gtm-event": "filter.click",
            "data-gtm-payload": "{\"event_category\":\"mainsearch\",\"event_action\":\"quickfilter.click\",\"event_label\":\"quickfilter\",\"position\":\"1\",\"location\":\"headline\"}",
            "data-metric-click": "mainsearch-catfilter-click"
          },
          "#text": "Kabellose Ladegeräte"
        }
      },
      {
        "@attributes": {
          "class": "catfilter-list-item"
        },
        "a": {
          "@attributes": {
            "href": "/URL/2021.html?q=link+value",
            "title": "Lautsprecher",
            "class": "catfilter-list-link",
            "data-gtm-event": "filter.click",
            "data-gtm-payload": "{\"event_category\":\"mainsearch\",\"event_action\":\"quickfilter.click\",\"event_label\":\"quickfilter\",\"position\":\"1\",\"location\":\"headline\"}",
            "data-metric-click": "mainsearch-catfilter-click"
          },
          "#text": "Lautsprecher"
        },
        "#text": [
          "",
          ""
        ],
        "a": {
          "@attributes": {
            "href": "/URL/2021.html?q=link+value",
            "title": "Lautsprecher",
            "class": "catfilter-list-link",
            "data-gtm-event": "filter.click",
            "data-gtm-payload": "{\"event_category\":\"mainsearch\",\"event_action\":\"quickfilter.click\",\"event_label\":\"quickfilter\",\"position\":\"1\",\"location\":\"headline\"}",
            "data-metric-click": "mainsearch-catfilter-click"
          },
          "#text": "Lautsprecher"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt solution, however, I'd like to accomplish the above without introducing a new dependency, if possible.